# TRIGGER AUTONOMOS TRANSACTION fails each time when trigger needs to run with different ORA errors

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sql-update

I try to create a custom table, which is created properly. The last 2 fields are matching the type from Orders table. The trigger's idea is when a certain date field is changed to INSERT this into the new table. The trigger is created in Oracle correctly, but once the field in question changes I get ORA errors (below) and cannot find out why they appear.

ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back

ORA-06512: at "shc.trigger_table_1", line 20

ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'shc.trigger_table_1'

I tried changing the datatypes, tried introducing an EXCEPTION, tried removing the :old.info23 check.

Here is the table I am creating:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
id number generated by default as identity,
table_name varchar2(20),
field_changed varchar2(20),
old_value date,
new_value date,
changed_by varchar(20),
date_of_change date,
orderRef varchar(50),
Ref varchar2(256));
```

Here is the problematic trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_table_1
AFTER UPDATE ON consignment
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
DECLARE
my_AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR varchar2(50);
my_AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2 varchar2(256);
BEGIN
IF :OLD.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON <> :NEW.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON AND :old.info23='I' THEN
Select AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR, AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2
Into my_AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR, my_AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2
From orders
Where orders.nr = :old.ordernr;
insert into table1(table_name, field_changed, old_value, new_value, changed_by, date_of_change, orderRef, Ref)
values ('consignment', 'ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON', :OLD.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON, :NEW.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON, sys_context('userenv','OS_USER'), SYSDATE,  my_AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR,  my_AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2);
END IF;
END;
END;
```

Comment: Why have you made the trigger autonomous? If this worked (and you'd need to commit that autonomous transaction...) then you'd get a row inserted into `table1` even if the update on `consignment` was rolled back - was that really your intention?

Comment: I have had a similar case before and in order to get the references from Orders table I had to use autonomous transaction. Other than that I do not know fully why it is/or is not needed. I need to insert in table1 only if there is a change that occured in Consignment table.

Comment: I imagine that was for a trigger on the orders table itself, and was to get around a mutating table error. Probably not the best option there either *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, it was for a table referring to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you don't commit your autonomous transaction. If you change it to commit at the end:

```
...
END IF;
END;

commit;

END;
/
```

then it will work - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AKCzbA7o). (You don't need the nested block, but it doesn't stop it working... and you could do `insert ... select ...` to avoid needing any local variables...)

But as you can see from the db<>fiddle result, if the update on `consignment` is rolled back then the insert into `table1` is retained, since that was committed independently.

If you remove the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;` instead then that won't happen. Then you won't need to, and indeed can't, commit within the trigger. You would just need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_table_1
AFTER UPDATE ON consignment
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  my_AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR varchar2(50);
  my_AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2 varchar2(256);
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON <> :NEW.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON AND :old.info23='I' THEN
    Select AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR, AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2
    Into my_AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR, my_AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2
    From orders
    Where orders.nr = :old.ordernr;

    insert into table1(table_name, field_changed, old_value, new_value, changed_by, date_of_change, orderRef, Ref)
    values ('consignment', 'ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON', :OLD.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON, :NEW.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON, sys_context('userenv','OS_USER'), SYSDATE,  my_AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR,  my_AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

or with `insert ... select ...`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_table_1
AFTER UPDATE ON consignment
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON <> :NEW.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON AND :old.info23='I' THEN
    insert into table1(table_name, field_changed,
      old_value, new_value,
      changed_by, date_of_change,
      orderRef, Ref)
    select 'consignment', 'ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON',
      :OLD.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON, :NEW.ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON,
      sys_context('userenv','OS_USER'), SYSDATE, 
      o.AEXTERNAUFTRAGSNR,  o.AUFTRAGSREFERENZ2
    from orders o
    where o.nr = :old.ordernr;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F9Er8Sen)

---

Incidentally, if you only want the trigger to fire if a specific column (or columns) was included in an update statement then you could do:

```
AFTER UPDATE OF ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON ON consignment
```

but you would still need to check it had actually changed. Your current check doesn't cover `ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON` being update to or from null, which is only potentially an issue if the column is nullable.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Really detailed! The use-case here is to capture the changes only and they will be happening after the initial INSERT of values into said columns. So the columns are NULLable, but I am interested only in the value change that is <> null. Also, I will be replicating the trigger to log multiple columns. Will give your suggestions a try today and will write back.

Comment: Thank you a lot Alex! Simple but it works. I removed the `AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION` and opted for `AFTER UPDATE OF ANKUNFTBELDATUMVON ON consignment`. Everything seems to be working perfectly.